# Can I configure an interrupt for a GPIO pin on a STM32F103ZE chip?

Tags: embedded, arm, interrupt, gpio

Is there any GPIO interrupt available for STM32F103ZE?
I went through the datasheet but didn't find anything related to that.
I am new to this processor but recently used TI's MSP430. 
In MSP430 we can configure interrupts using some GPIO registers. 
Can anybody tell me how can I do that?

Comment: Ensuing Meta question: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100606/somebody-rated-my-question-as-1

Comment: Better on [Electronics.SE]? Better check there first.

Comment: @dmckee I don't think so, but the question could use some clarification. Hari, please give more context. Are you designing a board (EE topic), or are you programming a firmware/driver (SO topic)?

Comment: I am programming the device using uVision 3 IDE

Comment: Please migrate it to http://electronics.stackexchange.com/ so Hari can get an answer.This question is reopened by some of our high reputationed people but it is unlikely that Hari will get a great answer about his subject here.The point of SO is not opening or closing questions it is helping people and what we should do with this question is to migrate it to somewhere more relevant.

Comment: Adding "embedded" tag so that maybe the question will get some answers on SO.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes.

Please [refer to the datasheet](http://www.keil.com/dd/docs/datashts/st/stm32f10xxx.pdf):

Section 8.1.3 states:

> #### External interrupt/wakeup lines
>
> All ports have external interrupt
> capability. To use external interrupt lines, the port must be
> configured in input mode. For more information on external interrupts,
> refer to:
>
> - Section 9.2: External interrupt/event controller (EXTI) on page 174 and
> - Section 9.2.3: Wakeup event management on page 175.

If you check out section 9.2.5 you'll find that you have to set up the external interrupt peripheral (EXTI) in order to map the pins you want to observe into the correct interrupt.

Re-read sections 8 and 9 of the data sheet, and make certain you understand how each EXTI register needs to be setup to listen on the correct GPIO lines, and to trigger on the correct type of transition.